# How to add mapview and buttons in the same layout?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am trying to create a `layout` consists of `mapview` and `textfield` and `buttons` align at the bottom of the `layout`

I tryied using this `xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/google_maps"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="@string/maps_key" />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView 
            android:text="@string/txtLocationDescription" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/editText1" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"></EditText>
        <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button1" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="@string/btnAddNewLocation"></Button>
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:id="@+id/button2" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="@string/btnCancelAddingLocation"></Button>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I got this error :

```
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.uis/com.android.uis.LocationManagementActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.android.uis.LocationManagementActivity.onCreate(LocationManagementActivity.java:10)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     ... 11 more
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     ... 21 more
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:291)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:264)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:247)
09-28 14:49:47.476: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455):     ... 24 more
```

What is the problem and how may I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put things inside a `MapView`.  A better solution is to put the `MapView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and lay out the buttons on top of it inside the top-layer `RelativeLayout`.

EDIT:

Basic example:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <MapView></MapView>
   <Button></Button>
   <Button></Button>
   <TextView></TextView>
   *****Any other layout you want ****
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want inside it.. below it :)

Comment: the layout is ok ,as far as map view is concerned. map view xml ends where it starts. MapView doesn't have any children.

Comment: Then take everything outside the `MapView` and place it in the `LinearLayout`.  It will push the map up and put everything below it for you.  Also, I don't see a close tag for `com.google.android.maps.MapView`.

Answer (score 2):

Your activity should extend MapACtivity for this exception not to occur. look at this line in your crash log.

```
MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use relativelayout, alignparent variants.